# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to class properties in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model:

```
public class DataResult<T>
{
    public List<T> ViewResults;
}

public class oGateEntryViewModel 
{
    public DataResult<GateEntryModels> oListGateEntryModels { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
GateEntryViewModel oGateEntryViewModel = new GateEntryViewModel();
IGateEntryBC oIGateEntryBC = new GateEntryBC();
oGateEntryViewModel.oListGateEntryModels = oIGateEntryBC.oGetGateEntryData();  --Error 
return View(oGateEntryViewModel);

oIGateEntryBC.oGetGateEntryData(); -> This method is returning the list Results.


public List<GateEntryModels> oGetGateEntryData()
{
    DataAdapters oDataAdapters = new DataAdapters();
    List<DataParameters> oListparams = new List<DataParameters>();
    DataParameters oDataparam;
    oDataparam = new DataParameters("@TYPE", SqlDbType.Int, (Int32)GateEntryEntities.EnumGateEntry.GateEntryList);
    oListparams.Add(oDataparam);
    DataTable dtList= oDataAdapters.GetData<DataTable>(oListparams, "PROC_GATEENTRY");

    return dtList.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new GateEntryModels()
    {
        GEID = int.Parse(i["GE_ID"].ToString()),
        GE_NO = i["GE_NO"].ToString(),
        TRANSPORTER = i["TRANSPORTER"].ToString()
    }).ToList();  
}
```

I'm trying to wrap multiple list results into a single models and bind the model in to view. When I tried to assign the list value into `oListGateEntryModels` property, its throwing an error. How do I fix this?

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<TS.Models.GateEntryModels>`' to '`TS.Models.DataResult<TS.Models.GateEntryModels>`'

Comment: This compiles? I don't see an oGateEntryModels object, which you are trying to return as a View. The most obvious type problem, though, is that you are expecting the compiler to implicitly convert a List<GateEntryModels> to a DataResult<GateEntryModels>. You could write an extension method to handle the conversion, you could convert it explicitly (depending on the object inheritance chain, it may accept an explicit cast) or you could just update the type in the ViewModel.

Comment: I would note that the antiquated use of hungarian notation (the "`o`" in "`oIGateEntryBC`") makes the code harder to read for C# developers who don't typically see it anymore.

Comment: I used to create an object like this only ,To identify the difference of class objects and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to "convert" a list to a type that *contains* a list, which is not directly possible.

The easiest solution would be to assign the property instead:

```
oGateEntryViewModel.oListGateEntryModels.ViewResults = oIGateEntryBC.oGetGateEntryData();
```

or

```
oGateEntryViewModel.oListGateEntryModels = new DataResult<GateEntryModels>
    {
        ViewResults = oIGateEntryBC.oGetGateEntryData()
    };
```

if you need to initialize the `oListGateEntryModels` property first.

Comment: oGateEntryViewModel.oListGateEntryModels = new DataResult<GateEntryModels>
    {
        ViewResults = oIGateEntryBC.oGetGateEntryData()
    };

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the conversion explicitly, try this to convert:

```
List<GateEntryModels> listName = dtList.AsEnumerable().Select(i => new MyType()
{
   GEID = i.Field<string>("GE_ID"),
   GE_NO = i.Field<string>("GE_NO"),
   TRANSPORTER = i.Field<double>("TRANSPORTER ")
}).ToList();

return listName;
```